# Find the intersection of two point series?

Tags: python, algorithm

A line is here defined as a series of 2D node points. Now, I have two such lines `A` and `B`.

```
A=[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2.1, 3), (4,7)]
B=[(2, 0), (2, 6)]
```

When one draws them on the paper, one can easily see the two lines intersect at a point that is **NOT** a node member of either `A` or `B`.

However, both `A` and `B` **indeed cross this point**. That is, the point indeed lies both on `A` and `B`, just not collide with the node points.

I now wish to find the intersection point.

*(a gentle reminder once again: the intersection is on `A` and `B`, but it may not be a node)*

What I come up with now is to use a polynomial to fit each point series. In this way, I can solve for the intersection with the equations. However, it seems to be a quite stupid way to myself.

Is there any smart way to do so?

I am speaking Python, but any generic answers are also very much welcomed.

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried.

Comment: Why would you fit a polynomial unless the points in each set represent points from a polynomial ?  Why not just regard the two sets as two sets of straight line segments and figure out their intersection(s) ?  `O(n^2)` I suppose, not sure of the complexity of polynomial construction and intersection off the top of me head.

Comment: determine the ecuation for line A and for line B and resolve the system having a point which respects them both

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark   Yeah, this is exactly what I am asking. How to *figure out their intersection(s)* given the discrete points.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0, len(A), 2):
    line1 = A[i:i+2]
    for j in range(0, len(B), 2):
        line1 = A[j:j+2]
        point_of_intersect = intersection(line1, line2)
        if point_of_intersect:
            print point_of_intersect
```

where the function `intersection` is defined according to [this Wikipedia entry.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-line_intersection)

Answer (score 0):

Having 2 points `X(x1, x2), Y(y1, y2)`, you can determine the line equation such as:

```
(x-x1)/(x2-x1) = (y-y1)/(y2-y1)
```

Do this for line A and line B.

You will obtain for line

```
A: y = m1*x+n1
B: y = m2*x+n2
```

Now, you just need to find the value of y and x which respects both equations above.

Answer (score 0):

If your lines have very few segments, then testing all possible segment pairs is practical, but it doesn't scale very well.

The most common solution to this problem is the [Bentley-Ottman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm) algorithm. It's easy to search the internet for pseudo-code or even libraries which implement it; it's a simple sweep-line algorithm whose execution time is `O( (n + k) log n)` where `n` is the number of line segments (the sum of the segments in both lines) and `k` is the number of intersections. If you only want to know if there are any intersections, you can stop at the first intersection found, at which point the algorithm reduces to `O(n log n)`.

This assumes that you know that `A` and `B` do not contain internal crossings. A naive implementation of Bentley-Ottman (where the two sets of line segments are just processed indiscriminately) will report all crossings, including self-crossings.